# What is the olden name for sideburns?

Tags: single-word-requests, early-modern-english

Upon search, I found out that *sideburns* has evolved from *burnsides*, named after the Civil War veteran and Rhode Island senator Ambrose Burnside. [See here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/sideburns-meaning-origin)

But surely sideburns existed before him, so what where they called then? Simply *beard on cheeks/sides of face*?

Comment: The OED's first reference is 1876 - but *Burnside* is mentioned in the etymology. Previous appellations listed are "side whiskers" and "side hair".

Comment: @WS2 As you have access to better sources than I do, could you post an answer; I will certainly up-vote it.

Comment: This piece from BBC News gives a lot of info on the history: https://www.bbc.com/ideas/videos/a-hairy-history-of-sideburns/p07d40lm?playlist=eponyms-explored

Answer (score 11):

The style shown in your link was called...

[mutton-chop ***beard***](http://beardstyle.net/modern-mutton-chop-sideburns/)

also

***[mutton-chop whiskers](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mutton-chop-whiskers)***

> Mutton chop beards are so named because they resemble a piece of chopped mutton, particular when shaped correctly. They’re characterized by sideburns that are chopped, or cut, along with the lower jawline and extend to the chin.

This only refers to the luxuriant type of facial hair style as pictured in your link. It is still in use today.

The phrase seems to go back to approximately 1845, [according to N grams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutton-chop%20whiskers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutton%20-%20chop%20whiskers%3B%2Cc0)

However, some probably just referred to them as

[***whiskers***](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=Bl9UAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA104&dq=%22whiskers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU46LMqYDjAhUR11kKHSTYDqAQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22whiskers%22&f=false)

[image]

Notice that in the descriptions in Prints of English Heads, "whiskers" is listed separately from styles of beards.

> …Black Cap, Hair, Whiskers, peaked Beard, Band…

In the next transcript, from the [*The Conspiracy Trial for the Murder of the President: And the ..., Volume 2*](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=50sTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA77&dq=%22side%20whiskers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS2oeUkYPjAhVrp1kKHZ1MDFY4ChDoAQgwMAI#v=onepage&q=%22side%20whiskers%22&f=false)

[image]

> Q: Do you think he has a mustache only, or a mustache and ***side-whiskers***?
>
> A: I cannot undertake to say that were any ***side-whiskers.***..

So it appears that what we call side-burns now was originally called either
***side-whiskers***,or  ***mutton-chop whiskers*** (also mutton-chop beard)  , depending on the style. What I found confusing in the search was that "whiskers" was *also* used to describe a *mustache*.

Beards have come and gone in a variety of styles for men, but the "sideburn" was probably only seen after 1800, and then only as part of a beard.

Comment: [Walker's pronouncing dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/walkerspronounc00unkngoog#page/n422/mode/2up) (1828) says "hair growing on the cheek unshaven; the mustachio." So *whiskers* seems to have meant non-chin facial hair. (Unless *mustachio* meant *sideburns*, which I doubt.)

Comment: @PeterShor gotta look it up, but just before we lost service here I was looking at a portrait of King Charles, in which he was described as "having two pencil-line whiskers"...an obvious reference to his mustache. I'm on the point of trashing this post, or radically revamping it.

Comment: Don't trash it; revise it. Two names for them were *side whiskers* and *mutton-chop whiskers*. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutton-chop+whiskers%2Cside+whiskers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutton%20-%20chop%20whiskers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cside%20whiskers%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmutton%20-%20chop%20whiskers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cside%20whiskers%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: There are references in google books to "side whiskers" dating from 1853, although the frequency of occurrences increases in the 1860s and 70s.
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22side+whiskers%22&safe=off&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB778GB778&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1880,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=b48QXf_REZLHgQbnoY64CQ&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwi_xY-F34HjAhWSY8AKHeeQA5c4FBDy0wMIVA&biw=1920&bih=969&dpr=1

Comment: Thank you @PhilMJones for the link

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor for the link.

Answer (score 7):

The OED confirms *BURNSIDE* as a precursor to *sideburns*.

> ‘A style of beard such as that affected by General Burnside (1824–81),
>   consisting of a mustache, whiskers, and a clean-shaven chin’ ( Cent.
>   Dict. Suppl. 1909). Frequently plural. Also attributive. Cf. sideburn
>   n. 1875   Cincinnati Enquirer 6 July 2/1   His whisker was of the
>   Burnside type, consisting of mustache and ‘muttonchop’, the chin being
>   perfectly clean.

1881   I. M. Rittenhouse Jrnl. in Maud (1939) i. 36

> The older one has lovely burn-sides.

1907   Outing 50 279   Such

> various patterns of ornamental whiskers as the ‘Piccadilly Weeper’
>   (No. 2), the ‘Burnside’, etc.

1930   Publishers' Weekly 8 Feb. 679

> In the days of copper-toed boots and burnsides..our grandfathers were
>   buying this book.

*Sideburns* 
Etymology:

> Apparently an alteration of Burnside n., **after side-whisker n. at
>   side n.1 Compounds 3, side hair n. at side** n.1 Compounds 1c(b), etc.

orig. U.S.
Thesaurus »
Categories »

> A strip of facial hair grown by a man down each side of his face in
>   front of the ears. Usually in plural. 1876   People (Indianapolis) 8
>   Apr. 2/4   Norris and Warner want to be fashionable. They are
>   cultivating side-burns.

1887   Chicago Jrnl. 1 Aug.   McGarigle has

> his mustache and small sideburns still on.

1936   G. Greene Journey

> without Maps ii. iv. 197   He was..handsome in his native robe and his
>   sideburns.

1985   Times 31 Jan. 13/5   The world will not be won or

> lost on the fall of a fringe or the length of a sideburn. 2004   T. C.
>   Boyle Inner Circle ii. iv. 298   The manager was a very proper-looking
>   character with swept-back hair, silvered sideburns and the trace of an
>   Italian accent.

**The text in bold above - re "side-whiskers" and "side-hair" answer the question**.

Comment: @Cascabel The answer is "side-whiskers" and/or "side hair". "Whiskers" can refer to any facial hair. My own grandfather's moustache, when I knew him in the 1940s/50s, was referred to, by an older generation as his "whiskers".

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, long side-whiskers were also known as "dundrearies" (the term seems to be early 20th century at latest).

Comment: Yes, but Lord Dundreary is a character from the 1858 British play Our American Cousin by Tom Taylor, which is around the same time frame as Senator Burnside.